# Do Heroku accept apps with Paperclip uploads now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

My bro told me I need to install Amazon S3 on my app in order to use Paperclip. However, I just pushed my app to Heroku production server and I can upload images no problem. I don't have S3 installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Amazon S3 if you want your uploaded images persisted across future application deployments and scaling actions.

You are able to upload to Heroku without Amazon S3 but you'll find your images disappear after you redeploy/scale your application - redeploying recompiles a slug for your app from the git repo whilst scaling to more than one dyno means the assets wouldn't be available on the other dynos.

And you don't as such 'install S3' - you just make use of the Amazon S3 service for storing your assets.